# How to correctly refresh aws credentials with Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to use the RefreshableCredentials module from botocore in order to manage automatically the credentials update.

```
import boto3
import botocore
from botocore.credentials import RefreshableCredentials
from botocore.session import get_session

def get_aws_credentials(aws_role_arn, session_name):
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
    assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn = aws_role_arn,
        RoleSessionName = session_name,
        DurationSeconds = 900
    )
    return {
        'access_key': assumed_role_object['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
        'secret_key': assumed_role_object['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
        'token': assumed_role_object['Credentials']['SessionToken'],
        'expiry_time': assumed_role_object['Credentials']['Expiration'].isoformat()
    }

def get_aws_autorefresh_session(aws_role_arn, session_name):
    session_credentials = RefreshableCredentials.create_from_metadata(
        metadata = get_aws_credentials(aws_role_arn, session_name),
        refresh_using = get_aws_credentials,
        method = 'sts-assume-role'
    )

    session = get_session()
    session._credentials = session_credentials
    autorefresh_session = boto3.Session(botocore_session=session)

    return autorefresh_session, session_credentials
```

Generating the credentials like this:

```
arn = "1234"
session = "Test"
session, credentials = get_aws_autorefresh_session(arn, session)
```

And then I'm passing the session_credentials from get_aws_autorefresh_session to wathever function may need them.

With this approach, I've noticed that everything works, but after 300 seconds this exception is raised:

```
get_aws_credentials() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'aws_role_arn' and 'session_name'
```

On the contrary, if I modify the function `get_aws_credentials` eliminating the variables, and passing static values for them:

```
def get_aws_credentials():
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
    assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn = "1234",
        RoleSessionName = "Test",
        DurationSeconds = 900
    )
    return {
        'access_key': assumed_role_object['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
        'secret_key': assumed_role_object['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
        'token': assumed_role_object['Credentials']['SessionToken'],
        'expiry_time': assumed_role_object['Credentials']['Expiration'].isoformat()
    }

def get_aws_autorefresh_session():
    session_credentials = RefreshableCredentials.create_from_metadata(
        metadata = get_aws_credentials(),
        refresh_using = get_aws_credentials,
        method = 'sts-assume-role'
    )

    session = get_session()
    session._credentials = session_credentials
    autorefresh_session = boto3.Session(botocore_session=session)

    return autorefresh_session, session_credentials
```

Everything works smoothly.

My question is how to retrieve the credentials using variables for the role_arn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a partial function using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) like this:

```py
from functools import partial

...

session_credentials = RefreshableCredentials.create_from_metadata(
        metadata = get_aws_credentials(aws_role_arn, session_name),
        refresh_using = partial(get_aws_credentials, aws_role_arn, session_name),
        method = 'sts-assume-role'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a good fit for a lambda usecase

```
session_credentials = RefreshableCredentials.create_from_metadata(
    metadata = get_aws_credentials(aws_role_arn, session_name),
    refresh_using = lambda: get_aws_credentials(aws_role_arn, session_name),
    method = 'sts-assume-role',
)
```